# invalid header field error while running in appace tomcat a war file

Tags: eclipse, war

I have build a web app from eclipse and it got successfully get the war file and run as server using tomcat 9. It is also run from eclipse and api response is also as expected. But if I run directly from tomcat as I have to deploy on lenux server it gives me error

```
01-Sep-2023 16:48:12.179 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.initInternal Failed to read manifest from [D:\tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.78-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.78\webapps\benchmark-metric-rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF]
java.io.IOException: invalid header field
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:404)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:234)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:81)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:73)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet.initInternal(DirResourceSet.java:293)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:715)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4607)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4740)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:922)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
```

01-Sep-2023 16:48:12.200 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [D:\tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.78-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.78\webapps\benchmark-metric-rest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:662)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1910)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:824)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1617)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:893)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1328)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1318)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:922)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@52e677af]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4607)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4740)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.io.IOException: invalid header field
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid header field
at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:404)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:234)
at java.util.jar.Manifest.(Manifest.java:81)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:206)
at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:184)
at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:139)
... 45 more

Comment: How did you build this war file? What is its manifest, given that's what the error message is referring to?

Comment: I have use eclipse maven to build that:

Comment: it is created at all no file present after building it